# How to print the \n character in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have the following string in Python: `thestring = "123\n456"`

In my Jinja2 template, I use `{{thestring}}` and the output is:

> 123
>   456

The only way I can get Jinja2 to print the exact representation `123\n456` (including the `\n`) is by escaping `thestring = "123\\n456"`.

**Is there any other way this can be done directly in the template?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer my own, maybe it helps someone who has the same question.

This works: `{{thestring.encode('string_escape')}}`

Comment: Why not `{{ thestring|e }}`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with `\n`. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escape

Answer (score 5):

For me `{{thestring.encode('string_escape')}}` failed with the following error:

```
escape_encode() argument 1 must be string, not AnsibleUnicode
```

Not sure what I did wrong, but the following worked just fine for me:

```
{{ thestring | replace('\n','\\n') }}
```